# Missing partial in Rails 4 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, partial, cocoon-gem

in my simple project I decide to use nested form and using for it cocoon gem. but after implementing it I get Missing partial error, although I have partial file with underline. this is my cocoon logic code:

**_form.html.erb**

```
... form_for starts...

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3>Ingredients</h3>
        <%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |ingredient| %>
            <%= render 'ingredients', f: ingredient %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to_add_association "Add", f, :ingredients %>
    </div>
  </div>

...submit and cancel buttons...
```

this is my partial file **_ingredients.html.erb**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :count %>
  <%= f.text_field :count %>

  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove", f %>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

it's working after rename the partial file to _ingredient_fields.html.erb. ingredient in single, and fields in plural

Comment: Thank you, my issue is resolved, but do you know reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for a file named _ingredient_fields. I assume it's cocoon providing the link_to_add_association method and it needs more partials.